# How is the | symbol read in Elm?

Tags: syntax, elm

Consider the following example code:

```
-- Update the fields of a record. (It must have the fields already.)
{ person |
  name = "George" }

-- Update multiple fields at once, using the current values.
{ particle |
  position = particle.position + particle.velocity,
  velocity = particle.velocity + particle.acceleration }
```

*Source: [Learn Elm in X Minutes](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/elm/)*

How is one supposed to read `|` in this example, and in Elm generally?

I'm familiar with it in set-builder notation as "where" / "such that", and in list comprehensions in Haskell it has a very similar purpose, e.g.

`[ x*2 | x <- [1..10] ]`

is logically equivalent to

[image]

*source: [Learn You A Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out)*

(Obviously I'm also familiar with its use as the unary "or" operator in C-like languages)

What about something like `type Msg = Increment | Decrement` ?

Source: https://guide.elm-lang.org

Or, in this example when discussing [Union Types](https://guide.elm-lang.org/types/union_types.html):

```
type Boolean
    = T
    | F
    | Not Boolean
    | And Boolean Boolean
    | Or Boolean Boolean
```

Comment: I don't know how official it is, but I always say "where". For example, person where name equals George.

Comment: @Joe But what about something like `type Msg = Increment | Decrement` in https://guide.elm-lang.org ?

Comment: The context is important. In that situation I say "Or". type Msg is an Increment or Decrement. Not sure why this didn't post on the first comment.

Comment: It is just a separator, you do not read it. When you enumerate items (e.g. apples, bananas and oranges), you also do not pronounce the comma.

Comment: @JanTojnar Thanks. I'm not sure why the explicit explanation of it is absent from the documentation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In types I read it as '*or*'. In the counter example:

```
type Msg = Increment | Decrement
```

I would read it as "a `Msg` is `Increment` *or* `Decrement`". In a slightly more complex but still common example of the `Result` type:

```
type Result error value
    = Ok value
    | Err error
```

I would read "a `Result` is either `Ok` with a `value` *or* `Err` with an `error`".

In the example you give of the record update syntax, I would read it as '*with*' rather than '*where*'. For example:

```
{ person | name = "George" }
```

is "the `person` value *with* its `name` field set to `"George"`" (rather than "*where* the name = 'George'" which seems to imply that you're filtering based on what values are in `person`). This one is I think more ambiguous than the type case though.